# Error message "wrong application" is displayed when I call the API for verifying the purchase token. How do I resolve this?

Tags: android, kotlin, in-app-purchase, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-iap

I have integrated HUAWEI IAP into my app and called the {rootUrl}/applications/purchases/tokens/verify API by referring to the official documentation, but error message {"responseCode":"8","responseMessage":"wrong application"} was returned.(document link:https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/api-order-verify-purchase-token-0000001050746113-V5 )

Answer (score 0):

To minimize the access to private user data (including order data), Huawei only retains the latest purchase of a product by a user. Once after a user buys a product and completes payment, the product is delivered and the `consumeOwnedPurchase` API is called, and the order is complete and closed. **In this case, do not call the verifying API for an earlier order**. Otherwise, the error will occur.